# rewrite rule to rename slug on specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want a RewriteRule that masks a slug for a simpler name on a specific domain. So I came up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} example\.com$ 
RewriteRule simpleName someWeirdLongName [L]
```

But this doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Question is not clear on what URL you intend to make and and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think even for a secure domain you have to use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ 
RewriteRule simpleName someWeirdLongName [L]
```